# R- Computing mean under special conditions

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following syntax in R:

```
n=12
x=c(2,7,2,6,8,3,1,8,3,7,8,3)
z=sample(c(0,1),n,replace=TRUE)
dat=rbind(x,z)
sdat=apply(dat,1,sum)
p=sdat[2]/n
```

I want to compute mean of x when z takes values of 0 and 1.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Since you seem to be a new user, I suggest you [take this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
tapply(x, z, mean)
       0        1
3.666667 5.222222
```